# Fetch the process details in Windows using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, process, windows

I am trying to fetch the list of all the processes (and their details) running on Windows using C/C++. I have made use of the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx to fetch all the processes. However it returns  for some of the processes because of access restrictions and also doesn't return the directory of the executable file associated with the process.

Is there a way by which the process ID and the location details of the executable associated with the processes running on a Windows machine be accessed ?

Comment: What do you suppose should be done with the processes you don't have the requisite privileges to access information about? Are you hoping to just ignore this problem? The OS wouldn't be very secure if it allowed that, now would it?

Comment: @CodyGray That's a valid point and I totally agree. OS does needs to have these restrictions to provide security. I was anyway interested in knowing about any alternatives(if they exist) which can only read all the processes and their related information.

Comment: Apparently what you're not understanding is that allowing an unprivileged user to observe and retrieve information about privileged processes would be a security hole. There's not going to be a way to do that. At least, not a *supported* way. That means certain processes will be effectively off-limits to most users. Maybe you can explain *why* you're trying to do this, and we can suggest a more reasonable path to pursue? What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My intentions are plain and simple. I am trying to build an application to replicate the Windows's Task Managers behaviour and I landed up with this question. Well, can you throw some light on how the directory information of the processes be accessed ?

Comment: this is very bad and not professional example. really for enumerate processes you need or `Process32First` and `Process32Next` or more effective `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation,`. if you want get full path by process id  - exist `SystemProcessIdInformation` for `ZwQuerySystemInformation` - with this you can get path without any privileges. however of course some process information require ability open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (with debug priviledge you can open any process) and `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` - already you stop on protected processes